# What commands can I use to login anonymously to a Windows share?

Tags: authentication, windows

I just learned that there are shares on a Windows server that allow anonymous logins.

How can I access those shares from my PC?  Do I simply need to use IP address or there is some command in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special commands. If the share is visible to you on the network and allows anonymous access, then all you need is the [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#UNC_in_Windows) path and you can access it.

For example, if the share is called `openShare` and its IP is `1.2.3.4` or its resolvable name is `openServer` then you an access it by simply typing the following:

```
\\1.2.3.4\openShare
```

**OR**

```
\\openServer\openShare
```

and if its visible to you, your PC has the proper network access to it, and it allows anonymous access, it will simply open up and you can browse it. If it doesn't allow anonymous access, you will be prompted with a Login/Password window and if you have no network access to it, it will simply pop up saying access failed.

Another more GUI based and novice approach to it (in case you don't know the path and the share name) is to simply double click on Network or Network Places on your desktop, via explorer or via control panel and it will do a search of the neighboring systems that are visible to you and when you double click the machine, it will show you any shares that are exposed and visible to you and you can double click on it and gain access that way. The UNC path is most direct if you know the information as this method can take some time while it searches and on some machines can make it unresponsive until it is done so people panic.

Another method available is when you finally know the path, using whichever method, you can mount the path for future use as a drive letter and even set it to remount each time you log on (if its something you use often) and you simply give it the UNC path and a drive letter in the GUI and you are done (you can also do it by command line but why bother right?)